# How to proxy | forward | nat masquerade all traffic sourced from an IP to another IP elsewhere

Tags: iptables, proxy, nat, firewalld, masquerade

I am setting up a new public network IP/24.
Sooner or later my old subnet public network IP/24 will be dropped.
In the meanwhile I would like to create a proxy to move all traffic to the OLD to the new subnet. I am thinking about a 1:1 NAT over internet.

So when somebody goes to an old IP, I would like that it is proxied to the new IP.

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.9  ->  YYY.YYY.YYY.9
XXX.XXX.XXX.10 ->  YYY.YYY.YYY.10
XXX.XXX.XXX.11 ->  YYY.YYY.YYY.11
XXX.XXX.XXX.12 ->  YYY.YYY.YYY.12
```

and so on.

I tried to setup a Proxy server but I cannot find a good reference on the internet to write the right setup for firewall-cmd/iptable
What I have done is:
First I added a new Virtual IP to the proxy server called XXX.XXX.XXX.99
Then I configured the proxy resolution:

```
# enable IP forwarding
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

# enable Masquerade
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-masquerade

# create routing rule:
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 nat PREROUTING 0 -d XXX.XXX.XXX.99 -j SNAT --to-source YYY.YYY.YYY.99
```

But I get:

```
Error: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables-restore -w -n' failed: iptables-restore v1.8.8 (nf_tables):
line 3: RULE_INSERT failed (Invalid argument): rule in chain PREROUTING
```

It seems that every reference say something different also is not clear if i should use SNAT, MASQUERADING or DNAT for this purpose.

Every help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible to implement the way you think.

Even if you are able to set NAT on the original network, the problem is return traffic. All IP packets from YYY.YYY.YYY.0/24 network need to be forwarded back to XXX.XXX.XXX.0/24 network. Then the machine at XXX.XXX.XXX.0/24 can replace the source IP address of the packets to be XXX.XXX.XXX.0/24.

A concrete example:

1. Client sends packet: src IP 192.0.2.1, dst IP XXX.XXX.XXX.0/24.
2. The NAT gateway changes destination address to YYY.YYY.YYY.0/24. Packet src IP is 192.0.2.1, dst IP is YYY.YYY.YYY.0/24.
3. YYY.YYY.YYY.0/24 sends response packet to 192.0.2.1. src IP YYY.YYY.YYY.0/24, dst IP is 192.0.2.1.
4. Now, if YYY.YYY.YYY.0/24 has normal routing, it sends the packet directly to the client. Client receives packet with src IP YYY.YYY.YYY.0/24, dst IP 192.0.2.1. The client does not expect packet from this source address, so it drops the packet.

To accomplish proper operation, you would need to set up default route on the machines at YYY.YYY.YYY.0/24 to XXX.XXX.XXX.0/24. However, setting up the default route means that YYY.YYY.YYY.0/24 is not directly reachable from the internet - you need to always access it via XXX.XXX.XXX.0/24.

You need to look back at the actual problem you are trying to solve and think of something else.